# "rails server" not working, sqlite3_native symbol not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I'm getting this error message when I try the "rails server" command... not really sure what's going on?

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle: dlsym(0x1010621e0, Init_sqlite3_native): symbol not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle (LoadError)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5/lib/sqlite3.rb:6
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:122:in `require'
from /Users/grace/Documents/web_stuff/tutorbookrails/config/application.rb:7
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:52:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:52
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:49
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6
```

Comment: have you run bundle install ? have you install sqlite db server?
paste your gemfile here

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reinstalling the '**sqlite3-ruby**' gem?

There might be some sqlite-ruby interface issue in your system as this SO answer, [Sqlite3 error after Rails 3 (beta 4) install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027363/sqlite3-error-after-rails-3-beta-4-install), points out.

And also, you should use [rvm](http://beginrescueend.com/)/[rbevn](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) and ruby 1.9 if there isn't any specific requirement for ruby 1.8.

Comment: The `sqlite3-ruby` gem is now simply  `sqlite3`.